# What is MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener “code 973”?

Tags: java, android, stream, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am running a stream via MediaPlayer.

I use MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener to get info on the streaming process.

Here is my code:

```
 mPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int infoCode, int i2) {
                Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener: " + infoCode);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I get infoCode = 973.

I can't find it in the documentation : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

What does it mean ?

Comment: What exactly does the log print when you find that infoCode?